# How to return an object from a selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I have a code

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#boxone') = new Category();
    $('#boxone').playFunction();
    foo();
})

function Category(el) {
    this.playFunction() {
        alert('bar')
    }
}

function foo() {
    $('#boxone').playFunction()
}
```

This first playFunction() works fine, but foo() returns undefined.

Comment: Does `$('$boxone').playFunction()` work correctly in the first part of the code you have posted?

Comment: Your first line doesn't matke any sense. You can't assign to a function call.

Comment: This looks like it's better suited to be implemented using the [plugin architecture](https://github.com/guidobouman/jquery-plugin-boilerplate).

Comment: Why does your selector begin with `$`?

Comment: @user1680977 yes, works perfectly.

Comment: @Barmar, sorry typo.

Comment: I wouldn't expect this to work at all.  Normally one would initialize a plugin on a set of selected elements, not instantiate that set to an object.

Comment: You need to show more code between the two playFunction calls. Otherwise all I can say is that somewhere along the way you set it to undefined ...

Comment: Are you sure the first line isn't something like `var boxone = new Category()`?

Comment: Where is `playFunction()` defined? It might require you to destroy it before running it again on the same element.

Comment: Your code as written does not work at all. `this.playFunction() { .. }` is invalid syntax, and `$('#boxone') = ...` is invalid.

Comment: The above code is very confused and could never work as it missuses jQuery in several ways. Please explain what you are trying to solve with this code. You will get better results :)

Comment: @Erick: Consider turning that into a plugin like this example: http://jsfiddle.net/4800Lyu5/

Comment: @Brad Christie: based on the code above, you had better provide an instruction manual with that example :)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie: Already linked to the plugin (in a previous comment), and the "new" code is at the bottom (and commented) of the jsfiddle. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

As i understand Category() is a class to create a game within the element with id = boxone .If this is true, it will be good to create a plugin .(http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/).

Doing so the code can be changed to -

```
$('#boxone').Category();
```

And the functions like playFunction() could be an event based function-

```
$('#boxone').trigger('play');
```

In the plugin , a listener will be attached on 'play' event for which the handler will be playFunction();